# Typescript Nested This Not Calling Defined Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, nested, this

I'm working on an app using Ionic 2 Beta and Typescript. I'm hitting some sort of error from the way `this` interacts when nested in Typescript, but I can't quite get my head around it. Here is my code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, params: NavParams, platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
        try {
            this.num = params.get("num");
            this.unprocData = params.get("data");
            var image = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('unprocImg');
            image.src = this.unprocData;
            image.onload = function() { console.log("images loaded"); this.proc(this.num); }
            //some stuff
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Problem Starting Render // " + err);
            this.navCtrl.push(IndexPage);
        }
    });
}

proc(num) {
    try {
        console.log("starting render...");
        switch(num) {
            case 0:
                this.procImg1(function() { //process the image for default vintage greyscale
                    this.load(this.procData, this.descriptionPoster1, "assets/img/Poster1.png", 250, 310, .6, .6);
                }); break;
            ..
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Problem Starting Render // " + err);
        this.navCtrl.push(IndexPage);
    }
}

test() {
    this.proc(0);
}
```

Interestingly, the function `test()` works as expected, but when calling `this.proc(..)` from inside of the `image.onload(..)` I get the error `this.proc is not a function`. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` is different when this:

```
image.onload = function() { console.log("images loaded"); this.proc(this.num); }
```

Is executed, and that's because the regular function that you are using does not save the context for `this` for when it is executed (it's asynchronous).

You can do:

(1) Use the arrow function as you have above that:

```
image.onload = () => { console.log("images loaded"); this.proc(this.num); }
```

(2) Use `bind`:

```
image.onload = function() { console.log("images loaded"); this.proc(this.num); }.bind(this)
```